# how i can add more sound inputs to desktop pc how to do this?

Tags: desktop-computer, sound-card

I want to add more sound inputs to desktop computer like line in or mic but no. of input should not less than 7.

Now i have two mic inputs and one line in. I want to make my own home studio for recording purpose.

Basically i want to do is to record 8 tracks individually at the same time with sone means.

Is it possible,to do this with some sound cards or external/internal hardware?

how i can do this?

Comment: What type of sound card do you currently have? If you have three effective inputs now (line in, mic) you won't be able to send more input into the sound card without splitting the inputs or upgrading your hardware. I.e., sending two inputs into one port by using a y-connector, but which will reduce recording quality and you'll have to manage both inputs on the same channel. Do you have an external mixer board?

Comment: Yup i have mixer board but it will give only stereo output. i want to give 8 sound signal to my pc. speccy shows realtek high defination audio for recording devices. Can i add another sound card to my pc which have 8 inputs for mic??

Comment: Certainly, but your chance of finding a sound card with eight inputs is slim to none. Short of giving specific product recommendations, for a more effective setup I recommend using a USB-connected external device, such as one of the external boxes by M-Audio or Lexicon Alpha, etc. Alternatively, you can get a USB mixer that won't require an input other than USB and can be easily managed with a digital audio workstation.

Comment: Coastly for novice. do u know about any sound cards for taking 10 inputs?

Answer (score 4):

The most affordable and effective option is probably purchasing new hardware, if you're dead set on using +/- 8 audio inputs. Do know that you can record tracks and then use a software mixer (plenty of free programs for this, such as Audacity) to merge them and do most of your work one track at a time without purchasing anything.

In regards to hardware, you have several options. To avoid buying an entirely new, professional-grade sound card, you can most likely get by using a **USB mixer/USB Audio Interface**. This takes 4 or more inputs and sends the data through USB to your computer, freeing up the inputs on your sound card. You can choose which device to use (sound card vs USB input) within Windows. [ASIO drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Stream_Input/Output) will reduce latency so you can even play/mix in real time on the computer. External mixers might start around $70 and increase in price dramatically along with the number of inputs. This seems like one of the only affordable options. There are [a variety of examples](http://www.musicradar.com/news/tech/13-of-the-best-budget-usb-audio-interfaces-570850) at this website so you understand the devices I'm talking about.

Other than purchasing hardware,  you are probably better off using the line-in you already have to record one or two tracks at a time. This would work unless you're performing live.

Comment: I understand (anecdotally) that PCI-based interfaces are a better choice when you start to try and sample 4 or more analog channels. The PCI ones have better bus access and potentially more hardcore ADC/DAC capability. 7 Channels is going to require professional-level hardware.

Comment: @Yorik: PCI has far superior throughput and stability, though hardware of the level he is requesting is going to potentially cost thousands of dollars. I've successfully used a USB audio interface with some professional software to do great recordings, though I only need 1-2 channels.

Comment: Me too, using onboard realtek (!) and also a USB pedal interface. I actually got better latency from the realtek, but again like you, only 1-2 channels at a time. Latency is the real enemy here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's definitely possible. There is a huge market for after market sound cards. I use one by ***AVID*** called the ***Mbox Pro***, which uses a ***FireWire*** connection and has about ***8 inputs*** or so. Also, it came with a copy of a software DAW called ***Pro Tools***.

There are many other different brands & devices, most of which support ***USB*** connectivity. FYI: You are more likely to find this kind of thing for sale at a musical instrument retailer than at a tech hardware store. Also, there are *heaps* of different music *(&)* production related forums online, including some ***Stack Exchange*** sites you might like to check out.

To get you started, some popular brands that I've used in the past that you might like to check out are: ***Behringer, Mackie, Tascam, Lexicon, Akai, M-Audio, Alesis, PreSonus, Focusrite, RME, MOTU*** *&* ***Native Instruments..*** *(and more..)*

Most audio production software is currently designed and marketed towards *Windows & Macintosh* owners/users. sometimes, however, I still use the free *&* open-source, *Linux*-compatible DAW classics ***Audacity*** *&* ***Rosegarden.*** There is also ***Ardour*** for *UNIX* which is *almost* free and quite well maintained. ***Bitwig*** is not free at all but *does* support *Linux*, resembles the ever-popular ***Ableton Live***, and is generally very nice. If you're not dedicated to *Linux* there are heaps of popular (some of which are quite expensive) *commercial* software DAWs like: ***FL-Studio, Cubase, Logic, GarageBand, Reaper, Acid, Reason, Ignite..*** *(just to name a few..)*

I hope you find at least some of this information useful.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to a cheap solution, you can get a mini usb sound card. something like a Sabrent USB External Stereo Sound Adapter. connect many of these to a usb hub, and you're off to the races. each device shows up as a separate sound input in softwares like audacity.